# Java design help. Inheritance and sharing code

Tags: java, oop

I'm still a bit of a noobie in programming development and am having some trouble with making a clean design. Specifically, I have a scenario as below:

I have 4 classes, each with common functionality. Lets call these methods A, B, C, etc.

class: Account ; methods: A, B, C, G, H, I, S1, S2, S3
class: Folder; methods: A, B, C, D, E, S1, S2, S3
class: Group ; methods: A, B, C, D, E, F, S1, S2, S3
class: Role ; methods: A, B, C, D, E, F, S1, S2, S3

The methods specified above are abstract. As in there could be a FooAccount and a BarAccount which implement method A differently. However FooAccount and FooGroup have the same method A (since they are of the same implementation; Foo). Not too bad, except there are also some methods S1, S2 and S3 that are implemented identically even between Foo and Bar so that FooAccount and BarAccount have identical methods S1, S2 and S3.

Currently my design is quite ugly:

**interface Object1:** declares A, B, C
**interface Object2 extends Object1:** declares D, E
**interface Object3 extends Object2:** declares F
**interface Account extends Object1:** declares G, H, I
**interface Folder extends Object2;**
**interface Group extends Object3;**
**interface Role extends Object3;**
**class Helper:** defines S1, S2, S3

I know multiple inheritances are prohibited for good reason, but if I were allowed to do so I could put the methods S1, S2, and S3 into Object1 and turn all the interfaces into abstracts. Then FooAccount could extend both Account and FooObject1.

Can anyone give me some advice to what structure might be better? Should I just put all A, B, C, etc. into a Util class (e.g. FooUtil and BarUtil)?

Answer (score 2):

You should group the methods in the interfaces according to role, not occurrance.  So assuming `A`, `B`, `C` belong to one role, `D` and `E` belong to another and `F` is in it own

```
interface Role1 - A, B, C
interface Role2 - D, E
interface Role3 - F
interface Account extends Role1
interface Folder extends Role1, Role2
interface Group extends Role1, Role2, Role3
```

If you have common implementation of methods, you can move them to an abstract base class that provides default implementations

```
abstract class Helper - S1, S2, S3
```

then you can declare your concrete classes

```
class FooAccount extends Helper implements Account
```

You could also consider using generics if you can extract behavior common to `Foo` and `Bar` and have `Account` be a generic class (taking `Foo` and `Bar`) instead of an interface

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unless I'm mistaken, since Account/Group are only interfaces, I'd have to write out the method A explicitly in each of the classes. I'm trying to reduce duplicate code as much as possible...

Comment: @kennyg - If you have common implementation of methods, you can mode those into an abstract class that you will inherit from (see the example with `Helper` -- you can certainly create more such helper abstract base classes for providing common implementation of `A`, `B` and `C`).  But as in your design the sharing revolves around `Foo` and `Bar` (all `Foo*` classes have the same `A` and all `Bar*` classes have the same `A` (which is different from the `Foo*` counterparts)), [cont.]

Comment: [cont.]  you should implement `A` in a `Foo` (also `Bar`) class that you pass to the  `Account`, etc. implementations, which in turn will call the passed-on object's `A` method.  This way the implementation is generic enough that you can easily come up with a `FooBar` class as well, and still capture the shared code properly

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on inheritance as a mechanism to reduce repetitive code. Instead, figure out a way to separate out the responsibilities into separate classes.

> FooAccount and FooGroup have the same method A

This tells me that the implementation of method A belongs in its own class (`FooA`). If it really makes sense for `Account` and `Group` to expose method `A`, then the implementation of `FooAccount.A` and `FooGroup.A` should simply be pass-throughs to `FooA.A`.

Comment: Could you possible go into more detail about pass-through's? Do you mean that FooAccount.A simply calls FooA.A?

Comment: @kennyg: Exactly. A simple method call doesn't violate the DRY principle in my opinion. The real logic that you want to avoid duplicating will reside in FooA.A, so if your other classes need to implement this method for the sake of your API, they can just delegate the responsibility to the FooA class.